# Web2py layout configuration settings

Tags: python, layout, default, web2py

The web2py online book in Chapter 3 Overview says that in the scaffolding application, values for `response.title`, `response.meta.author`, etc, are set in the file `models/menu.py`. While previous versions of Web2py did include the settings in `menu.py`, in `v.2.18.5` the default values are not set in this file. While some of the settings, such as `response.meta.author` etc are defined in `models/db.py`, `response.title` and `response.subtitle` could not be found in `db.py` also. The online book does say that these can be defined in any model file. Can someone advise where these settings are now defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that those items are no longer defined in the scaffolding app. The default layout simply using `request.application` as the page title if `request.title` is not defined. Feel free to define those items wherever, or not at all.